# Microsoft RDP Crash on launch

Tags: crash, remote-desktop, launchpad

I work for a primarily Microsoft based IT support company, anyway today a Mac user asked me to setup RDP which I wouldn't normally have any issues with but I got onto the Mac and installed the latest RDP client from the app store (this was updated a couple days ago).

Anyway when I try to launch it from launchpad I get a crash every time, I tried reinstalling but it still does the exact same.

I am not experienced with Mac's at all so I am finding it hard to troubleshoot this, can anyone shed some light on this or point me in the right direction?

```
Process:         launchd [571]
Path:            /Applications/Microsoft Remote Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Remote Desktop
Identifier:      com.microsoft.rdc.mac
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [133]

Date/Time:       2015-11-03 09:22:44.647 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          1197257 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           13
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   12
Anonymous UUID:                      CA434F00-4590-4545-832A-B884258E0AD6

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000055  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 0

Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1136
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5970H
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0253, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version of Mac OS X - Microsoft has dropped support for Mac OS X 10.7 and 10.8.

See this tech-net link for more info [OSX 10.7 Remote Desktop crash at startup](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5c7a7cfb-e129-4a55-908a-f7e211d385a7/osx-107-remote-desktop-crash-at-startup?forum=winRDc).

I believe that an Mac OS X update to 10.10 (El Capitan) is available free in the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question I didn't know this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the resolution to 'full screen' in the .rdp connection document the connection will crash when using a high res monitor, like 2560 x 1440. Too bad the max. res. with the old versions Remote Desktop Connection is limited to 1400 x 1050 but this setting works on a high res monitor. The newer Microsoft Remote Desktop has higher res options but no Applications tab anymore, where you can set a Windows application to auto start on login, and we need that.
btw:
'Old' RDC 2.1 still works on a MBP Touch Bar with MacOS Sierra.
If you use 'full screen' in the .rpd document on a lower native res. monitor like 1920 x 1080 it works fine.